# Дифференциация маски SVG и оригинальной формы SVG при анимации

Tags: html, css, css3, svg, анимация

Я хотел бы иметь возможность применить маску SVG к shape svg.

Я анимирую, но не позволяю элементу маски трансформироваться через анимацию. Другими словами, маска остается статической, а  фигуре преобразуется.

В примере ниже, как сохранить радиус внутреннего маскирующего круга в значении -`8px`?

```css
@keyframes ripple {
  0%{
  transform: scale(0.5);
  opacity: 0;
 }
 30%{
  opacity: 0.3;
 }
  50%{
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
 70%{
  opacity: 0.3;
 }
 100%{
  transform: scale(2.5);
  opacity: 0;
 }
}

.ripple {
  transform-origin: 50px 50px;
  animation: ripple 3s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <defs>
    <mask id="circle-mask">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>
      <circle r="8" cx="50" cy="50" fill="black"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>

  <circle id="main-circle" class = "ripple" r="15" cx="50" cy="50" mask="url(#circle-mask)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/50711357/7394871

Answer (score 3):

Оберните `<circle>` в элемент группы (`<g>`). Затем примените маску к группе.

```css
@keyframes ripple {
  0%{
  transform: scale(0.5);
  opacity: 0;
 }
 30%{
  opacity: 0.3;
 }
  50%{
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
 70%{
  opacity: 0.3;
 }
 100%{
  transform: scale(2.5);
  opacity: 0;
 }
}

.ripple {
  transform-origin: 50px 50px;
  animation: ripple 3s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <defs>
    <mask id="circle-mask">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>
      <circle r="8" cx="50" cy="50" fill="black"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>

  <g mask="url(#circle-mask)">
    <circle id="main-circle" class = "ripple" r="15" cx="50" cy="50" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50714226/7394871)